# Attempting to ignore local SSL certificate

Tags: perl, ssl, lwp-useragent

I'm attempting to use a perl script to retrieve information from a local machine running 3rd party software. I can view it with a web browser, but I need to automate it. The problem is that it appears to not like the SSL Certificate the software created when it was installed.

Not a problem says I. I'll just tell LWP:UserAgent to ignore the certificate. Hmmm... same error.

Here's the test script I'm using...

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use LWP::UserAgent;

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new( 'ssl_opts' => { 'verify_hostname' => 0 } );

my $response = $ua->get( 'https://192.168.1.50' );

print "\n\n";

if ( defined( $response ) ) {
    print $response->as_string;
}
else {
    print "No response object created.";
}

print "\n";
```

... and here's the response I get ...

```
500 Can't connect to 192.168.1.50:443 (certificate verify failed)
Content-Type: text/plain
Client-Date: Tue, 05 Nov 2013 16:42:53 GMT
Client-Warning: Internal response

Can't connect to 192.168.1.50:443 (certificate verify failed)

LWP::Protocol::https::Socket: SSL connect attempt failed with unknown error  error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed at /usr/local/share/perl5/LWP/Protocol/http.pm line 51.
```

From what I've read in the docs and the advice I've seen on various forums is that setting 'verify_hostname' to a false value should cause it to ignore an invalid certificate.

Any suggestions on what I'm missing?

Comment: it works for me , what version of perl and LWP ?

Comment: perl 5.14.3 - libwww-perl/6.05